# Setting Up PHP behind Nginx with FastCGI

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, php

I am trying to set up PHP on my server running nginx as reverse proxy. I have the following directive in the configuration file:

```
location ~ \.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

On opening any php script on the browser it says **500 Internal server error**. If I completely comment out this directive, the browser throws a dialog box giving an option to download the php script. All other files like image files etc. in the same directory as the php scripts are accessible. Where can there be a problem?

**EDIT:** The configuration file

```
upstream the_server {
server localhost:8000;
}

server {
    root    /var/www/linux-dash-master;
    listen  80;
    client_max_body_size    4G;
    keepalive_timeout       5;
    log_format timed_combined '$sent_http_x_username - $remote_addr - [$time_local]  '
    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" - '
    '$request_time $upstream_response_time $pipe';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/named.access.log timed_combined;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/named.error.log debug;
    location /linux-dash-master {
            alias /var/www/linux-dash-master;
            index index.html index.php;
    }
    # Pass PHP requests on to PHP-FPM using sockets
    location ~ /linux-dash-master/.*\.php(/|$) {
            alias /var/www/linux-dash-master;
            #fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            if ($fastcgi_script_name ~ /linux-dash-master(/.*\.php)$) {
                    set $valid_fastcgi_script_name $1;
            }
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/linux-dash-master$valid_fastcgi_script_name;
            #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
            #include fastcgi_params;
      }
      location /static/ {
          alias   /path/to/staticfiles/;
      }
      location / {
          proxy_pass          http://the_server;
          proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
          proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header    X-Remote-User-Name   $remote_user;
      }
```

}

Comment: well your title says fast cgi, but your settings are for fpm, which are you using ?

Comment: read nginx error.log!

Comment: what's the port 8000 for, and when will you pass to php or 8000 ?

Comment: @Mohammad AbuShady 8000 is the port on which the server listens. gunicorn process was started on this port as follows 'gunicorn wsgi --bind=127.0.0.1:8000 --daemon'

Comment: so if you have `.php` at the end you pass to php, and any thing else goes to gunicorn?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady Yes, that is exactly what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Check `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` does it exist?

If so check inside it, look for a line that starts with `listen`, does it point for a file or a port ?

Note that lines starting with `;` don't count

Comment: It is "listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock". I also tried using "listen = 127.0.0.1:9000" and appropriately changing configuration file. Still it doesn't work.

Comment: check the nginx log file, also make sure that the php server is actually running

Comment: One more peculiar thing which I noted using Inspect Element feature is that instead of returning JSON response all the GET requests calling the php scripts return an HTML page of 0kb size.

Comment: The 500 Internal server error is now gone. The php server is now running.But still there seems to be a problem while processing the php scripts. In fact, a very simple php script which prints "hello world" also shows blank page. Any ideas?

Comment: you need to check the nginx log, check `/var/log/nginx/error.log` or whatever the error file name is

Comment: No error now. Every get request returns 200 OK code. But the problem now is as I said above.

Comment: then check the fpm error log, probably called `/var/log/php5-fpm.log`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56134/discussion-between-user3286661-and-mohammad-abushady).